# CPU time > wall time in Python multihreading

Tags: python, multithreading

A wrote a short piece of code in Python that uses multiple threads (but a single process) and ran it with a timer:

```py
import random
a = "".join([chr(ord('a') + random.randint(1, 20)) for _ in range(50_000_000)])

def sum_part(i):
  part = a[i * 20_000_000: (i+1) * 20_000_000]
  size = 1_000_000
  splits = [part[j: j + size] for j in range(0, len(part), size)]
  hashes = [hashlib.sha1(bytes(k, "utf-8")).hexdigest() for k in splits]
  return "".join(hashes)

def calc_split():
  threads = [threading.Thread(target=sum_part, args=[i]) for i in range(2)]
  for t in threads:
    t.start()
  for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

I got these results:

```
CPU times: user 118 ms, sys: 36.7 ms, total: 155 ms
Wall time: 110 ms
```

If this was C++, user time > wall time would not surprise me: the CPU time corresponds to per-cpu-thread time. However, as I understand it, with GIL there should only ever be a single CPU thread involved. What am I missing?

Comment: The GIL is usually released by modules implemented in C. For example Numpy works reasonably well and can achieve almost full parallelization in a single process. I guess a small part of your program releases the GIL

Comment: Post the "short piece of code" you used. Otherwise we're all flying blind.

Comment: I posted a code to reproduce this. I don't understand how implementation details can explain it, though, as I thought that the interpreter will always use a single process and a thread returning GIL will only allow another to pop in its place, but never two running at the same time

Comment: `hashlib.sha1` will, for instance, be native code and it can probably release the GIL while it's doing its thing.

Comment: Does it mean that as sha1 released the GIL, it was still doing operations on CPU (user time counts), but as the GIL wasn't taken, the other thread could start doing its GIL-related (or not) operations in a different CPU thread?

Answer (score 2):

Certain workloads in Python will run in native code, and can free the GIL so that other threads can run in parallel.

In the case of this snippet the `.sha1` call very likely does that.

This brings about a popular misconception about Python being slow: a lot of things that would be "slow by nature", being CPU intensive, are delegated to optimized native code - that is the reason the language is so popular for big data, numeric manipulation, machine learning and other workloads: the idea is to have Python code with very little boilerplate and ease to orchestrate what needs to be done, while the heavy-lifting is made by these libs that more often than not release the GIL.

Answer (score 1):

The tool [gil_load](https://github.com/chrisjbillington/gil_load) shows that a single-threaded version of this program only holds the GIL 28% of the time.

```
held: 0.281 (0.281, 0.281, 0.281)
wait: 0.0 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
  <140589725390656>
    held: 0.281 (0.281, 0.281, 0.281)
    wait: 0.0 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Full benchmark program:

```
import random
import hashlib
import time
import gil_load

a = "".join([chr(ord('a') + random.randint(1, 20)) for _ in range(10_000_000)])

gil_load.init()

def sum_part():
    part = a
    size = 1_000_000
    splits = [part[j: j + size] for j in range(0, len(part), size)]
    hashes = [hashlib.sha1(bytes(k, "utf-8")).hexdigest() for k in splits]
    return "".join(hashes)

def calc_split():
    for i in range(100):
        sum_part()

gil_load.start()

t0 = time.time()
calc_split()
t = time.time()
print(f"Duration: {t - t0:.3f}s")

gil_load.stop()

stats = gil_load.get()
print(gil_load.format(stats))
```

Commenting out the line which calculates the SHA1, the GIL held percentage rises to 100%, which shows it is in fact `.sha1` which is releasing the GIL.